# XQUery collections: deleting?

Tags: html, collections, xquery

I am new to xquery, and I am trying to use a collection to reload my webpage and keep some information. My problem is after I create the collection and save my node using (sausalito) the collection stays alive even afterI close the program. Next time I use the collection it has nodes already in it. I only need the collection to save a node, then reload website and delete node. Problem is that I am not able to delete the collection or the nodes. I tried using delete-nodes() and other methods from http://www.zorba-xquery.com/doc/zorba-1.4.0/zorba/xqdoc/xhtml/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_xqddf.html#delete-index-1

What I have

```
declare collection resultview:collection as node()*;
declare variable $resultview:collection as xs:QName := xs:QName("resultview:collection");
declare sequential function resultview:add($allMovies as element(movies))
{
for $movie in $allMovies
return xqddf:insert-nodes($resultview:collection, $allMovies);
fn:trace(xqddf:collection($resultview:collection), "Collection data: "),
exit returning resultview:list();
};
declare sequential function resultview:deleteList() {
    let $a := ""
    return  xqddf:delete-index($resultview:collection);
    exit returning resultview:list();
};
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you saying you are using the collection for gathering one time results (e.g. just for that request)? If so, why use a persisting collection, and not just a in-memory sequence instead? Pass it around as argument, should work well enough..

Comment: That was my first approach, but it didnt work. Webpage is render, then hitting one link, it reloads and sets everything in a different order. Problem is that after it renders the first time, how do i send the parameters without saving them? I need to keep all the initial parameteres saved somewhere, and I thought about this. (again im new at this)

Comment: One option is to store the state as hidden parameters on the webpage, and make sure they are submitted on reload. Another option is to store the state in cookies, but browsers may reject them. Storing them server-side is a good option as well, but make sure to distinguish between 'sessions' (even without login), otherwise concurrent request could get mixed up. Sausalito provides example code that helps with sessions, might be worth to take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I do understand you correctly, this should work:

```
declare collection resultview:collection as node()*;
declare variable $resultview:collection as xs:QName := xs:QName("resultview:collection");

declare sequential function resultview:add($allMovies as element(movies))
{
  xqddf:insert-nodes($resultview:collection, $allMovies);
  resultview:list();
};

declare sequential function resultview:deleteList() {
  xqddf:delete-nodes(
    $resultview:collection,
    xqddf:collection($resultview:collection));
  resultview:list();
};
```

use delete-nodes instead of delete-index (the latter deletes a complete index and not a node at a specific index position).

does that help?